# Lerp between two images in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two images which have the same dimensions and only differ by the colors of a few pixels. Is it possible to lerp between the two images in some way? Looks like the dart:ui Image object does not give me low enough access to pixels, maybe there is some other way to get down there and do some lerping?

Comment: Could you not just fade in one over the other? Flutter isn't great at giving direct pixel access to images.

Comment: This works well enough for me. I would still like to hear from anyone who might know how to write a manual version. Looks like it would require going into deeper rendering code.

Comment: That's good. There is a library for interacting with an image, but it's incredibly slow and runs CPU only, so that's not going to do you much good.  The next best thing is playing around with blendmode and painting the images directly onto the canvas, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html